# How ro remove unwanted broken DAGs in airflow

Tags: airflow

I write something wrong in my `sql_test.py`,and run `python sql_test.py`,the error is  'no module named xxx',and in web-ui it shows a red error - Broken DAG.
And then I run `airflow list_dags` the same error occurs again .This is strange and I don't know what's happening.
I tried to run `airflow delete_dags sql_test` but there is no such id.
How can I :

1. remove the waning in web-ui
2. get `sql_test` out of `list_dags`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's some syntactical mistake in your dag-definition file, resulting in failure in parsing the DAG. When Airflow fails to parse a DAG, several functionalities get broken (like `list_dags` in your case)

---

Of course deleting the problematic dag-definition file would fix it, but that's not a solution. So here's how you can understand what's wrong and fix it

- From linux shell, go to [Airflow's logs folder](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/v1-10-stable/airflow/config_templates/default_airflow.cfg#L40)

  `cd $AIRFLOW_HOME/logs/scheduler/latest/`
- Run [`tree` command](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/61074/tree-command-for-multiple-includes-and-excludes) to see directory structure

  `tree -I "__init__.py|__pycache__|*.pyc"`
- [View the last few lines](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/29457/264216) of the log file of your corresponding broken dag

  `tail -n 25 /path/to/my/broken-dag.py.log`

This will give you the stack-trace that Airflow threw while trying to parse your broken dag file. That would hopefully help you diagnose the problem and patch it.

---

Once your dag-definition file is fixed

- the `broken dag` message would disappear from UI
- DAG would appear in the UI (refresh it a few times)
- `list_dags` command would also start working

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to repair your DAG and ignore it, you can remove the unwanted DAG by specifying the DAG's underlying file in an .airflowignore file.